# NSURLSesionDataTask Cancel Operation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, networking, nsurlsession

I am initiating network service using NSURLSessionDataTask. This is my sample code

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration= [XPURLSessionConfiguration setSessionConfiguration:config withAccessability:YES];

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self.baseURL,resourceURL]];
        NSLog(@"URL is %@",url);
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&eaerror];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
                if (httpResp.statusCode == 200) {

                    NSError *jsonError;
                    NSDictionary *notesJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                              options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                                                error:&jsonError];

                    NSLog(@"%@",notesJSON);
                    if (!jsonError)
                    {
                        success(notesJSON);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        failure(jsonError);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    failure([NSError errorWithDomain:@"Title" code:httpResp.statusCode userInfo:nil]);
                }
            }
            else{

                    failure(error);

            }
        }];
        [taskArray addObject:postDataTask];
        [postDataTask resume];
```

In the above code i am adding postDataTask into an array which i am using for cancel all operations.

This is my cancel operation.

```
for (NSURLSessionTask *task in taskArray) {
        if([task state] == NSURLSessionTaskStateRunning){
            [task cancel];
        }
    }
```

I am not sure about the cancelling all operations. What is right way to cancel all operations. Failure Block (i.e)failure(error) is not returning when i try to cancel operation.

Comment: failure block or the delegate method?

Comment: “once a task has been canceled the URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: delegate method will be called to enable you to update the UI appropriately. It's quite possible that after canceling a task theURLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:BytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite: method might be called again, however, the didComplete method will definitely be last” - from here http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2013/09/20/ios7-day-by-day-day-1-nsurlsession